# Insufficient Resources to execute plan on pool fastlane

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm running a Python script to load data from a DataFrame into a SQL Table using vertical python. However, the insert command is throwing this error:

```
(pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] ERROR 3587:  Insufficient resources to execute plan on pool fastlane [Request exceeds session memory cap: 28357027KB > 20971520KB]\n (3587) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

This is my code:

```
df.to_sql('TableName',engine,schema='trw',if_exists='append',index=False) #copying data from Dataframe df to a SQL Table
```

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your 'code': there is no actual `INSERT` query from what I can see. Either this is the reason for the error, or you are not including enough detail here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insufficient Resources error while inserting into SQL table using Vertica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478624/insufficient-resources-error-while-inserting-into-sql-table-using-vertica)

Comment: This definitely seems like a duplicate of what Monica pointed out. I'll answer on the other question ...